Enemy slide when colliding with the player
When the enemy is hit by the player, it will slide backwards until the end of the world. I'm using Terrain as the ground. Is there anything I need to add, or is there an additional LayerMask setting or something?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lookRadius = 10f;

    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    CharacterCombat combat;

    void Start()
    {
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        combat = GetComponent<CharacterCombat>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                CharacterStats targetStats = target.GetComponent<CharacterStats>();
                if (targetStats != null)
                {
                    combat.Attack(targetStats);
                }
                FaceTarget();
            }
        }
    }

    void FaceTarget ()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }
}


Before collide 
After collided 
It will slide until the end of the world 
It's okay if it still slide, I just need for it not slide too far.

Add some resistance look at the settings on your rigid body

Use a rigidboy and add friction. Don't modify the object's transform directly, instead apply forces to the rigidbody.
